# Passar array multidimencional por POST, e utilizá-lo no PHP para exportar em CSV

Tags: php, array

Já faz algum tempo que eu estou batendo cabeça para resolver esse problema. Eu preciso passar um array multidimensional por POST para usa-lo no PHP para exportar um arquivo CSV.

Vamos aos códigos!

No form eu tenho isso:

```
<form action="export.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="col pt-4 mt-2">                    
                    <input name="acao" value="export" hidden/>
                    <?php foreach ($retorno as $item): ?>
                        <input type="text" name="dados[]" value="<?php print_r($item);?>" hidden/>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary font-weight-bold" type="submit" value="Exportar"/>    
                </div>
            </form>
```

O `$retorno` está com o seguinte valor (Que está vindo de um código mais acima):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [mat_indicador] => 8646
            [nome_indicado] => nomeIndicado
            [tel_indicado] => 999999999
            [tel_indicado_op] => 
            [cpf_indicado] => 99999999999
            [status] => 0
            [sobrenome_indicado] => sobrenometeste
            [setor] => D.P.
            [nome] => teste
            [data_criado] => 2019-10-09 12:58:14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [mat_indicador] => 3696
            [nome_indicado] => nomeIndicado
            [tel_indicado] => 999999999
            [tel_indicado_op] => 
            [cpf_indicado] => 99999999999
            [status] => 0
            [sobrenome_indicado] => sobrenometeste
            [setor] => Fisioterapia 
            [nome] => teste
            [data_criado] => 2019-10-09 13:23:48
        )
)
```

No início do arquivo `export.php` eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$retorno = $_POST['dados'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['dados']);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Mas ele imprime os índices como string:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que eu estou usando para exportar é esse:

```
function export_data_to_csv($retorno, $filename='export', $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"'){
    // Tells to the browser that a file is returned, with its name : $filename.csv
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
    // Tells to the browser that the content is a csv file
    header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel;charset=UTF-8");    
    // I open PHP memory as a file
    $fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');    
    // Insert the UTF-8 BOM in the file
    fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
    // I add the array keys as CSV headers
    fputcsv($fp,array_keys($retorno[0]), $delimiter, $enclosure);
    // Add all the data in the file
    foreach ($retorno as $key => $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }
    // Close the file
    fclose($fp);
    // Stop the script
    die();
}
export_data_to_csv($retorno);
```

E dá problema porque o `array_keys` espera um array, mas está chegando uma string.

Os erros que dão são esses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o erro ocorre por que tu passa uma string no post e não um array, então o php não consegui identificar que é um array quando recebe os dados. Existe uma função que serve exatamente pra solucionar esse problema, [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

```
// formulario.php
<?php $retorno = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
        ],
    ];
?>

<html>
    <form action="export.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="col pt-4 mt-2">
            <input name="acao" value="export" hidden/>
                <input type="hidden" name="dados" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($retorno));?>" />
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary font-weight-bold" type="submit" value="Exportar"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

---

```
// export.php
<?php

var_dump(unserialize($_POST['dados']));die;
```

Resultado:

```
export.php:3:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 2
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado!